# MySQL Linux command line tool and properly formatted results

Tags: mysql, select, command-line

Does anyone know of a good tool to use from the shell to query the database and get **intelligible results**?

On the command line, from SSH, I want to query the database using `mysql` but the results are pretty much unreadable because there is no formatting for the terminal screen.

If I run the following it is vary hard to make sense of the results.

```
use mydb;
select * from db3_settings;
```

I know I could use phpMyAdmin or the MySQLCC but I'm looking for a command-line solution.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can obtain a vertically formatted output with `\G`.

This is the standard output:

```
mysql> select * from tblSettings;
+-----------+----------------+---------------------+
| settingid | settingname    | settingvalue        |
+-----------+----------------+---------------------+
|         1 | maxttl         | 30                  |
|         2 | traceroutepath | /usr/bin/traceroute |
|         3 | alertemail     | me@host.com         |
+-----------+----------------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And this is what the output looks like with `\G`:

```
mysql> select * from tblSettings \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
   settingid: 1
 settingname: maxttl
settingvalue: 30
*************************** 2. row ***************************
   settingid: 2
 settingname: traceroutepath
settingvalue: /usr/bin/traceroute
*************************** 3. row ***************************
   settingid: 3
 settingname: alertemail
settingvalue: me@host.com
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: It would be useful to include what `\G` means, also I believe `\G` is a terminator so you don't need a semi colon to terminate this otherwise an additional query is expected.

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of ways you can make results more readable.

**Using limit to only view a few rows:**

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10;
```

**Only returning select columns:**

```
SELECT a,b,c FROM table;
```

**Terminating your queries with `\G`** to send the current statement to the server to be executed and display the result using vertical format:

```
SELECT * FROM table \G
```

Answer (score 2):

For non-Windows systems, you can use `less` to make the output formatted or more readable.

```
mysql > pager less -SFX;
mysql > select * from databasename.table;
```

it pipes the sql output to less giving a tabular output that can be scrolled horizontally and vertically with the cursor keys. exit by pressing 'q'

if you don't want, reset by using

```
mysql> nopager
```

Answer (score 1):

In command line, you can get have the results of the returned records shown as individual, formatted records (as opposed to a long table) by using `\G` at the end of your query, like this:

```
select * from <tablename> \G;
```

Comment: This answer has been flagged as low quality. If it answers the question, consider adding a bit of text to explain how it works.